# JPA: why merge will update join table without cascade

Tags: database, session, jpa, cascade, staleobjectstate

Thanks for taking a look at this question in advance.

Basically, I have a few entities and here's the relationship.

Table `A` ---< Table `AB` >---- Table `B`

And the entity classes:

```
class A {    
     @ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(name = "A_B", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID",nullable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID", nullable = false) })
     private List<B> bList;
 }

class B {    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bList")
    private List<A> aList;
}
```

Now I have 2 sessions accessing the same `A` object. I changed the `bList`  value of `A` and saved it in session 1.  So now, the object `A` in session 2 is stale and I saved an object `C`, which has reference of object `A` in its stale state.

I wonder why WITHOUT using `cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE}` by putting it into the `@ManyToMany` annotations, saving object `C` would also update the stale state of `A` back into the database, so the changes I made about object `A` in session 1 is gone?

Comment: Did you ever find out how to solve this? I am having similar issues with "automatic" updates of a related table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887328/prevent-unwanted-cascaded-table-updates