# Prevent unwanted cascaded table updates

Tags: jpa, sql-update, cascade, openjpa, one-to-one

I am creating my first JPA based project. My application features several tables with foreign key relationships for integrity purposes. Many related tables are normalized lookup tables.

Consider the tables `Person` and `Account`, having a fk relationship on `accountid`:

```
+-Person----+               
| personid  |               +-Account---+
| accountid*|==============>| accountid |
| ...       |               | ...       |
+-----------+               +-----------+
```

In the front end (JSF), I created a form for new `Person` objects containing a `selectOneMenu` list with all accounts, and the selected *accountid* is added to the new *person* which is inserted correctly into the database.

*However, the `Account` table is also updated automatically and I cannot find a way to stop this from happening.*

My classes are annotated as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usr_person")
@NamedQuery(name="Person.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Person u")
public class Person implements Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="person_id")
    private int personId;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to UsrAccount
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="account_id",insertable=true,updatable=true)
    private Account usrAccount;

    ...
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="usr_account")
@NamedQuery(name="UsrAccount.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM Account u")
public class Account implements Serializable 
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="account_id")
    private int accountId;

    //bi-directional one-to-one association to UsrPerson
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="usrAccount")
    private Person usrPerson;

    ...
```

The front end calls the below method which simply uses the merge() function of `EntityManager` to persist the new `Person` object:

```
public String savePerson()
{
    try
    {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        person = em.merge( person );
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ...
```

This leads to an `UPDATE` call **for every object in the `Account` table**.

---

**UPDATE**

I removed the `EntityManager.merge()` call from my code *and the UPDATE statements are still there*. Somehow the JSF form leads to automatic updates of the `Account` objects backing it. The lines below are from the JPA trace:

```
17448 <snip> openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1905431636, conn 233456683> executing prepstmnt 1172878998 UPDATE usr_account SET loginname = ?, password = ?, privileges = ? WHERE account_id = ? [params=(String) mvreijn, (String) ba5edce0be3a9b8f6ac9b84c72935192b2289b3a341ad432021256c7144b59f4, (int) 90, (int) 1]
17449 <snip> openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1905431636, conn 233456683> [1 ms] spent
17449 <snip> openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1905431636, conn 233456683> executing prepstmnt 386904456 UPDATE usr_account SET loginname = ?, password = ?, privileges = ? WHERE account_id = ? [params=(String) afolmer, (String) ba5edce0be3a9b8f6ac9b84c72935192b2289b3a341ad432021256c7144b59f4, (int) 90, (int) 2]
17450 <snip> openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1905431636, conn 233456683> [1 ms] spent
17450 <snip> openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1905431636, conn 233456683> executing prepstmnt 1322606395 UPDATE usr_account SET loginname = ?, password = ?, privileges = ? WHERE account_id = ? [params=(String) annuska, (String) ba5edce0be3a9b8f6ac9b84c72935192b2289b3a341ad432021256c7144b59f4, (int) 80, (int) 3]
17451 <snip> openjpa.jdbc.SQL - <t 1905431636, conn 233456683> [1 ms] spent
```

These statements are executed when I `commit()` the transaction. For some reason the query and subsequent transaction leads JPA to believe all `Account` objects from the `selectOneMenu` are modified; how do I prevent this? Detach them first one-by-one?

---

**UPDATE 2**

My persistence.xml is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="matco">
        <class>matco.model.Changelog</class>
        <class>matco.model.Item</class>
        <class>matco.model.ItemAssignment</class>
        <class>matco.model.ItemMaintenance</class>
        <class>matco.model.LstType</class>
        <class>matco.model.LstColor</class>
        <class>matco.model.LstCondition</class>
        <class>matco.model.LstSize</class>
        <class>matco.model.Team</class>
        <class>matco.model.Account</class>
        <class>matco.model.Person</class>
        <class>matco.model.CatBrand</class>
        <class>matco.model.CatItem</class>
        <class>matco.model.CatPrice</class>
        <class>matco.model.CatSupplier</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/matco" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="****" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="****" />
            <!-- TODO remove this in favor of enhancement -->
            <property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>
            <property name="openjpa.Log" value="DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SCHEMA=TRACE, SQL=TRACE"/>
            <property name="openjpa.ConnectionFactoryProperties" value="PrintParameters=true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Meanwhile, I have detached the `Account` objects after I query them in the backing bean, like this:

```
public List<Account> getUsrAccounts()
{
    List<Account> accts = em.createNamedQuery( "Account.findAll", Account.class ).getResultList();
    for (Account acct : accts)
        em.detach(acct);
    return accts;
}
```

Then when I commit the new `Person` object, only the `Account` that is linked to the new `Person` is updated by JPA. Even that is undesirable, and I get the feeling that I am misusing JPA in some way.

What is the normal way to use a non-editable lookup table with JPA?

Comment: Fair enough. I find it difficult to locate the source of the `UPDATE` statements being executed; the only call my code makes in `EntityManager.merge( Person )` which IMHO should not touch the complete list of `Account` objects.

Comment: Jsf itself **never** issues update statements. It's always the jpa layer, which in turn looks for modified/newly created objects. Those are most likely created/modified by you (directly or from the ui). This kind of begaviour is easier to debug and test if you create unittests it becomes way easier.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that JPA is actually issuing the statements; however I cannot understand why the JSF form post is triggering JPA functions. How can I trace / troubleshoot the chain of events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not have `<property name="openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses" value="supported"/>` enabled in your persistence.xml. Figure out another enhancement strategy.

Comment: I know it should not stay that way - hence the TODO reminder for myself. Will enhancement solve my problem?

Comment: RuntimeUnenhancedClasses has some nasty bugs in it... so that is where I'd start.

Comment: I have added the enhancement to my project which was as pleasant as rootcanal work. **BUT it resolved the issue!** No more updates to tables that were not touched. Thanks a lot.

Comment: *(By the way, the OpenJPA project might consider updating the eclipse enhancement plugin from version 1.2.1 to 2.x, and the howto pages contain several omissions)*

Answer (score 1):

Try adding to your @OneToOne mappings `cascade=CascadeType.REFRESH)`
This will indicate to your ORM framework to cascade only on refreshes (while reading entity) and to not cascade on updates when trying to save only one of these entities.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but still the entire `Account` table is updated on `INSERT` of the `Person` table. See my edit for the actual trace lines.

Comment: It seems your JPA framework might be configured to autocommit somehow, which ORM engine are you using in your app? Can you post its global config ? like persistence.xml file ?

Comment: I have posted the `persistence.xml`, see UPDATE 2.

Comment: try also  these changes: @JoinColumn(name="account_id", nullable=false) -> to allow null values in account to be inserted while persisting a Person. and also: @OneToOne(mappedBy="usrAccount", optional=true).  Also try using cascade={} -> empty

Comment: I think you meant `nullable=true` . And yes, I should add that as well to prevent inadvertent errors, thanks.